# MONGO_URL not being picked up by Meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor app. and before running it I set the MONGO_URL like this:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/my-db"
```

I echo the env var to make sure it has taken using:

```
echo $MONGO_URL
```

and all is good. Anyway, when I then run:

```
sudo meteor run
```

the app. starts, with no errors, but the database that it is connecting to is not the 'my-db' database - it is connecting to the default 'meteor' database! How is this happening when I am explicitly setting the MONGO_URL beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one of two things:

**use the variable inline**

```
$ MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/my-db" meteor
```

**export the variable**

```
$ export MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/my-db"
$ meteor
```

An `export` is required in the latter case so the variable will be available to the subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you've defined it for your user's process, and not `root`'s.

Either use `sudo -E` to pass through your environment [variables], or run `meteor` and your script as the *same* user (related: why are you running it as `root` anyway? Probably not a good idea unless you're forced to)

Comment: I am running the app using 'sudo' because if I don't I get errors that focus around "Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file". Should I chown the .meteor directory to the user that I use to login to my virtual machine with?

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely fix your permission problems (don't forget `-R`) rather than hand away keys to the kingdom...

Comment: To help others, here is a good article to fix meteor application permissions: http://www.maxlibin.com/remove-sudo-meteor/